# Use of videocore library for video stream in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, videocore

I am using videocore library downloaded from this [link](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) and I also downloaded all code with cocoa pods. Ans run sample code separately with all related files without cocoa pods. When I am building the code there are many errors occurs says like `videocore/sources/iOS/GLESUtil.h` file not found and there are many files not found in this category. Please let me know how I will use these files into my existing own project.

I am using the header search path is `$(SRCROOT)` because these all files is in my root directory and set **Always Search User Paths**  to YES.

Thanks

Comment: That's not enough information to answer the question.  There is no detail about how you've set-up the *Header Search Path* etc.  Why is it getting so many upvotes?  It's not well asked and not of general interest.

Comment: Please see my edited question

Comment: And where is the `videocore` folder in relation to `$(SRCROOT)`?

Comment: This is in project directory

Comment: OK check the build logs and see what the `-I` options are being expanded to when passed to the compiler and check it's correct.

Comment: How will check the build logs. Actually I there is error like "#include <videocore/sources/iOS/GLESUtil.h>
" file not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84186/discussion-between-ravi-gautam-and-trojanfoe).

Comment: Are you able to build this. i am also facing the same issue in building the videocore code.

Comment: Yes, I have built this. I used many permutation and combination around 1 week then suddenly it was build.

Comment: @RaviGautam..when I am trying to run the sample app with my RTMP server it gives me this below error. Any Idea?

ClientState: 2
ClientState: 3
ClientState: 4
ClientState: 5
ClientState: 6
received server window size: 2500000
received peer bandwidth limit: 2500000 type: 2
Request to change incoming chunk size from 128 -> 4096
Received invoke
pktId: 1
received invoke _result
tracked command: connect
ClientState: 7
Received invoke
pktId: 0
received invoke onBWDone
ClientState: 11

Answer (score 0):

videocore sample project use the cocoapods. don't use the files which is attached already with it. use only samplebroadcast sample and use cocospods only.

Comment: I asked this question one year ago and I have successfully released that project  at that time. Thanks.